# What is the difference between 'page_source' and 'find_element_by_tag_name("body").text'?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Trying to find whether a text is present on UI login page (web-page).
I could verify it by `'driver.page_source()'` and `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text`

1. driver.page_source()

   ```
   text = "abcd"
    page_source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
    if text in page_source:
        return True
    else:
        return False
   ```
2. driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text

   ```
   text = "abcd"
    value = text in self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text
    if value:
       return True
    else:
       return False
   ```

1. What's the difference between method1 and method2 ?
2. Which one is preferred to do the required task ?
3. Which is faster ?
4. Or anySelenium-UI methods to be used ?

Any help would be appreciated. Looking for valuable inputs.
Any idea on this ? Any help here ?

Answer (score 0):

Page source will give all the text including HTML tags, styles etc. as you have written yourself in execute script to return the innerHTML. So, all HTML code will be returned which obviously will contain the text too. You can also get the whole html with selenium too instead of using JavaScript executor by browser.page_source.

On the other hand, browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text  will return all the text you see on the page without html tags.

To me, the 2nd method should be preferred and faster because you will have string of smaller length(without un-necessary html tags) and the actual text you are interested in.